# How can I format NavigationView title in Swift UI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Here's the snippet:

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
NavigationView {
        List(0..<N, id: \.self) { index in ... }
        .navigationTitle("Bold Title with leading alignment")
}
```

How can I change the formatting of a nav view's title to have it at the very top with non-bold font? For all other tabs  I use:

```
var body: some View {
VStack
{
    Text("ABC").font(.title) <-- centers at the very top with no-bold color
    
    Spacer()
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
```

Comment: Give us the full code, and explain clear what you want

Comment: You can change font of Large title (like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64304302/12299030) but not alignment.